Crashlytics : Binary Images section missing in production ENV
We are trying to get a full crash report and symbolicate a crash log from a customer.
As we recieve the log (in any format) we see that the binary images section is missing, which is crucial for us to obtain the address of the SDK and symbolicate the relevant functions in the crash.
Is there a specific configuration of Crashlytics that is affecting the presence of binary image section in the crash log?
Thank you
